# How to find local disk space by `df` command?

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems, disk-usage

`df` command can be used to list all mounted folder spaces. The output includes local disk, remote disk. Is there a way for me to get the disk usage only for the local disk? I'd like to filter out other types of mounted points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$ df -lh` would do the work.

Where [from man page],

> `-l, --local` - limit listing to local file systems
>
> `-h, --human-readable` - print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

Answer (score 3):

`df -l` should restrict the output to local file systems.

Alternatively, if you know that the device name of the local disk is, for example, /dev/sda, then you can use grep to filter out just those disks: `df | grep sda`.

Answer (score 0):

`df -l` is very handy if the df command is not working because of stale mounts.
That is one situation where `df | grep` would not work